# Insert mongodb nestle element in a particular index

Tags: mongodb, sorting, nested

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I have a `books` collection with a data structure as below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6539d19532f73ad544000001"),
    "name" : "PHP",
    "books" : [
        {"author": "jim", "title" : "Book1", "price":"200"},
        {"author": "joe", "title" : "Book2", "price":"300"},
        {"author": "amy", "title" : "Book3", "price":"500"}
    ]
}
```

Now I want insert a new object into the books section. The object is something like `{"author": "amy", "title" : "Book4", "price":"400"}`. So as the price is less then 500, so I want to insert that object before Book3. So my final object will be looks like somehow below.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6539d19532f73ad544000001"),
    "name" : "PHP",
    "books" : [
        {"author": "jim", "title" : "Book1", "price":"200"},
        {"author": "joe", "title" : "Book2", "price":"300"},
                {"author": "amy", "title" : "Book4", "price":"400"}
        {"author": "amy", "title" : "Book3", "price":"500"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not allow you insert an nested array element in a specific location. You can only add it to the end with `$push`. What you really need to do, is to restructure your schema. Instead of storing all `PHP` books in a nested array, you can just store each book separately, and add the keyword PHP:

```
{ "name" : "PHP", "author": "jim", "title" : "Book1", "price": 200 }
{ "name" : "PHP", "author": "joe", "title" : "Book2", "price": 300 }
{ "name" : "PHP", "author": "amy", "title" : "Book3", "price": 500 }
{ "name" : "PHP", "author": "amy", "title" : "Book4", "price": 400 }
```

(I've omitted the `_id` field from there)

Then you can always just do the sorting when retrieving books:

```
db.collection.find( { name: "PHP" } ).sort( { price: 1 } );
```

An additional benefit is is that you now never have to modify a document (unless a price changes of course). Not letting documents grow by adding elements is a good performance improvement. The number of documents per name (`PHP`) is now also unlimited as the nested books array was limited to a total of 16MB (the MongoDB document size limit).

Please also make sure you store the price as a number (`500`), and not as a string (`"500"`). It will be a lot easier to do calculations with later.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. So there is no way to insert an object at a particular position.